# using jquery/ajax/webmethod to update a listbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

i have a listbox that i want to update by using jquery/ajax to call a webmethod from a code behind page. the listbox displays all the users who are logged in (they're added to a global list on successful login). i can obviously get the listbox to update using full page refreshes, but this isn't aesthetically pleasing. i'm having two problems.

1. when i run the app in chrome, and check network activity via dev tools, i can't see the webmethod being called. i have other webmethods that (i can see) are being fired/executed as expected.
2. i wrote the script based on a example i found, so i'm not entirely sure (i'm relatively new to these areas) if i'm (a) getting the data from list correctly (i just want the username to be displayed) and (b) appending it to the listbox correctly.

here's the webmethod:

```
[WebMethod()]
    public static string[] getCurrentList()
    {
        int count = 0; 
        for(int i = 0; i < Global.ListUsers.Count(); i++)
            count++;

        string[] results = new string[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            results[i] = Global.ListUsers[i].Username.ToString();**//edited...** 
        }                                            

        return results;
    }
```

and the script:

```
$(function updateListbox() {
var lBox = $('select[id$=ListBox1]');
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (req) {
            req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "Homepage.aspx/getCurrentList",
        data: "json=" + JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var results = data.d;
            if (results.length > 0) {
                var updatedList = [];
                for (var i in results) {
                    updatedList.push(results[i]);
                }
                $(lBox).append(updatedList.join('\n'));
            }
            else alert("No new items to update...");
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

});

all help and suggestions welcome and appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You don't want anything in the data field unless you are passing parameters into the function. Just leave that field out, and it should work fine.

I've also never needed to use the beforeSend parameter, but your scenario may be slightly different.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up, i didn't actually know what the data field was for. however, the reason i have that in the data field is becuase i was getting a server 500 error from developer tools in chrome, and after a search, that was a solution i found - it stopped the error, but i can't see the webmethod being called as stated above. i have another webmethod queryInvitedBy which i can see being called every 5 seconds (as expected) so i'm at a loss as to why i can't see getCurrentList being called.

Comment: i took what's in the data field out; i can see the webmethod firing now, but i'm getting that error again: "500 internal server error". If i look into the preview/response to the request i see: "Object reference not set to an instance of an Object".

Comment: Step through your C# code to see exactly what's throwing the exception. Your first for loop is missing brackets...

Comment: single lines of code after statements can be inline, with, or without brackets. i'll paste stack trace below as there's not enough room in this comment.

Comment: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","StackTrace":" at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException"}

Comment: OK, I just wasn't sure what exactly was supposed to be contained in the first for loop.

Comment: For the data part you should be able to use `data: "{}"` - have a read of http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Actuallly the problem seems to be AJAX call property data. Please modify data property as follows:

```
data: "{}",
```

No need to send any parameters ("json=" + JSON.stringify(data). Your web method does not contain any parameters). Also as per servarevitas answer, beforeSend parameter is not required the ajax call already specified the content type as Json.